# How can I access the subfolder that I get the permission of parent folder with Android Storage Access Framework

Tags: android, subdirectory, storage-access-framework

As you known, Android Q has force to use Storage Access Framework if you use the Environment Storage Directory. However I have let the user to choose the root folder Storage root directory(Environment Storage Directory) as the root folder that I can build a child named A folder int it. Then I need to add more folders into A folder. But there are some problems.

I used these codes to get the root parent folder permission.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
                | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PREFIX_URI_PERMISSION
                | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(intentType)) {
            intent.setType(intentType);
        }
        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
```

Then I get the uri from on onActivityResult(). I can create a child folder named A folder via this uri and permission.

```
  public static String createDirByUri(Context context, String uri, String dirName) {
        if (context == null || TextUtils.isEmpty(uri) || TextUtils.isEmpty(dirName)) {
            return null;
        }
        DocumentFile parentDocumentFile = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, Uri.parse(uri));
        DocumentFile childDocumentFile = parentDocumentFile.findFile(dirName);
        if (childDocumentFile != null) {
            return childDocumentFile.getUri().toString();
        }
        childDocumentFile = parentDocumentFile.createDirectory(dirName);
        if (childDocumentFile == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return childDocumentFile.getUri().toString();
        }
    }
```

But then I use the A folder to create another one folder that it create the folder in the uri parent directory not in the A folder.

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (data != null) {
                String demoDir = FileUtils.createDirByUri(this,data.getData().toString(),"A");
                Log.e("demoDir", demoDir);
                String childDir = FileUtils.createDirByUri(this,demoDir,"child");
                Log.e("child", childDir);
            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

How can I fix it? Help me, please.

Comment: `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
                | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PREFIX_URI_PERMISSION
                | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);`. Rempove that all. It doe not make sense. You cannot grant anything here.

Comment: `But then I use the A folder to create another one folder that it create the folder in the uri parent directory not in the A folder. `. That is worded pretty unclear. Do you want to create folders ../A/child and you get ../A and ../child ?

Comment: Yes, I want to create a child folder of A folder named child, then I need to access the child folder.

Comment: Your code does already create ../A/child.. I tested it.

Comment: Did u test it in Android Q devices? I tested it with emulator that it just be created the level as A folder not as a child.

Comment: I also tested with emulator Pixel 2 Android Q.